# KonvaJS: Avoid blurriness when zooming in/out

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

I'm using KonvaJS to draw some figures and make simple animations.

Sometimes a user zooms-in in the page and the drawn canvas gets blurry.

I've noticed that if the page starts zoomed in, the blurriness is greatly reduced. So I thought a solution would be to rerender the stage with the new zoomed value. But I don't know how to do that.

I tried setting `Konva.pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio` then calling `stage.draw()` (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55524612/3290971), but redrawing isn't enough to remove blurriness. I don't know what would work.

I have [this JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/toketacuyu/edit?html,js,output) that will render a text and a circle. The circle changes color every second, but this is just to see that the interval is working.

At each second, the `Konva.pixelRatio` is updated, then `stage.draw()` called. When you zoom in, you'll see both text and circle get blurred and stay blurred at each step.

I also noticed that when calling `stage.toDataURL({ pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio })`, the resulting URL contains a non-blurred image. This is the effect I want to get. I don't know how.

Here's a video of the problem in the JS Bin (the moment the blurriness is gone is when I refresh the page):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already created layers don't update their pixel ratio automatically. So you have to do it by yourself:

```js
// update global for new layers
Konva.pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
// update pixel ratio of existing canvas
layer.canvas.setPixelRatio(Konva.pixelRatio);
```